# Does anyone know why this error is popping up when using a masm code on visual studio 2019?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2019, masm

Here is the actual code:

```
extrn ExitProcess : proc

.DATA
num QWORD 80
sum QWORD ?

.CODE

_main PROC
 mov rax, num
 add rax, 20
 mov sum, rax

xor rxc, rcx
call ExitProcess
_main ENDP
END
```

And when using the debugger I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: helloMASM, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Assembling HelloMASM.asm...
1>HelloMASM.asm(16): error A2006: undefined symbol : rxc
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(70,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Debug\HelloMASM.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaHelloMASM.asm" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "helloMASM.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any idea of why this is happening?
Also, I have noticed that I don't have the "register" option in the following pattern on the visual studio:

```
Debug->windows->registers
```

All I have is this:
[image]

I tried reinstalling the program but still persists. Any clue would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "undefined symbol : rxc" You misspelt `rcx`

Comment: OMG how I couldn't notice that one!
No more errors now, thank you!

Comment: however, I don't know yet why I can't find the "registers" option in the "debug" menu options

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I misspelled "rcx" with "rxc" so writing it right fixed my problem. Also, the "register" option under "debug" menu showed up once I clicked the debugger. Thank you for the help!